# ThinkTecture.IdentityModel "The type 'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityToken' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced

Tags: thinktecture-ident-model, thinktecture-ident-server

I start using ThinkTecture.IdentityModel in my project and I am facing a serious issue. Please help me on the same.

Error   1   "The type 'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityToken' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.IdentityModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try manually adding the System.IdentityModel dll reference from the assemblies. This is what worked for me.

-Right click project, add reference

-Assemblies, Framework, System.IdentityModel v4.0.0.0